# Forge - Does POST Fetch Specific Properties from Model Derivative support SVF1?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When using the GET Fetch All Properties endpoint we can specify the x-ads-derivative-format and set it to 'fallback' to retrieve SVF1-compatible objectids. Is this option supported for the POST Fetch Specific Properties endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POST properties` does’t support **SVF1** compatible IDs currently, one workaround is to call `GET properties` endpoint to generate **SVF1** compatible IDs, and then use `POST properties` to query data you want.

Comment: When I try the GET properties I often get a 404 - any reason for that? thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you sometimes call that BEFORE the SVF got generated?

Comment: it seems to return a 404 because of large model. However the model is about 200MB

Comment: Not the size of the model but the amounts of properties in it that *might* count when using that endpoint. Are you using "forceget"? https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/#query-string-parameters